# R OpenCL Package installation failed: ERROR: OCL not set

Tags: r, opencl

Package installation failed. I tried it both with manipulating the makevars and not. Probably a rookie error, but there is no documentation. I installed OpenCL drivers via Nvidia Cuda toolkit.

```
install.packages("OpenCL")
```

```
Installiere Paket nach ‘C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)
Paket, das nur als Quelltext vorliegt und eventuell Übersetzung von C/C++/Fortran benötigt.: ‘OpenCL’
installiere Quellpaket ‘OpenCL’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/OpenCL_0.2-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20881 bytes (20 KB)
downloaded 20 KB

* installing *source* package 'OpenCL' ...
** Paket 'OpenCL' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation

ERROR: OCL not set!

You will need a working OpenCL SDK with headers
and libraries for both i386 and x64

Set OCL to the root of the SDK

You can also set individial variables OCLINC,
OCL32LIB and OCL64LIB. If they are not set,
the default layout will be assumed.

ERROR: configuration failed for package 'OpenCL'
* removing 'C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/OpenCL'
Warning in install.packages :
  Installation des Pakets ‘OpenCL’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
```